# Work around for 'too many values' error in stata after roccomp command

Tags: stata, roc

I have a data set of 140 000 observations, and am trying to compare the ROC (receiver operating characteristics) using two different predictors. However, the `roccomp` command fails with an `r(134)` error which reports `too many values`.
I am using Stata/MP 12 if that makes a difference.
Is there a work around for this?

Answer (score 1):

Interested in others' comments but the following seems to work.
Download the `somersd` package via `ssc install somersd`. And then using the c-statistic transform, the c-statistic with confidence intervals is produced very quickly.

`somersd truth_var test_var, tr(c)`

I am not sure how to construct a significance test to compare two variables but it is immediately obvious whether the confidence intervals overlap.